# Why Iam getting ReferenceOutOfRangeException while PlayerPref a list in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am getting this error while saving the position of a list of objects using PlayerPref in unity.

my code. And the highlighted line is the line the unity directs me when click at the error.
[image]

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: What is `enePosX` and are you sure it has the same amount as (or at least) `LFE.Count` ...?

Comment: Both are lists.